# Apps keeps crashing on click of the weather button

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I'm trying to click the "weather" button on my main class, but when I click it, it will crash it.
The main class just like an empty project only will have a few button functions in it.
The second weather class is the function that can display the weather.

How to fix the problem... Thank you!

logcat

```
2020-11-23 00:22:19.342 24196-24196/? I/example.weathe: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
2020-11-23 00:22:19.435 24196-24196/? W/example.weathe: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86_64
2020-11-23 00:22:20.020 24196-24196/com.example.weather W/example.weathe: Accessing hidden method Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;->getOpticalInsets()Landroid/graphics/Insets; (light greylist, linking)
2020-11-23 00:22:20.021 24196-24196/com.example.weather W/example.weathe: Accessing hidden field Landroid/graphics/Insets;->left:I (light greylist, linking)
2020-11-23 00:22:20.021 24196-24196/com.example.weather W/example.weathe: Accessing hidden field Landroid/graphics/Insets;->right:I (light greylist, linking)
2020-11-23 00:22:20.021 24196-24196/com.example.weather W/example.weathe: Accessing hidden field Landroid/graphics/Insets;->top:I (light greylist, linking)
2020-11-23 00:22:20.021 24196-24196/com.example.weather W/example.weathe: Accessing hidden field Landroid/graphics/Insets;->bottom:I (light greylist, linking)
2020-11-23 00:22:20.080 24196-24196/com.example.weather W/example.weathe: Accessing hidden field Landroid/view/WindowInsets;->CONSUMED:Landroid/view/WindowInsets; (light greylist, reflection)
2020-11-23 00:22:20.094 24196-24196/com.example.weather W/example.weathe: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->getAccessibilityDelegate()Landroid/view/View$AccessibilityDelegate; (light greylist, linking)
2020-11-23 00:22:20.154 24196-24196/com.example.weather W/example.weathe: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (light greylist, reflection)
2020-11-23 00:22:20.155 24196-24196/com.example.weather W/example.weathe: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (light greylist, reflection)
2020-11-23 00:22:20.206 24196-24196/com.example.weather D/OpenGLRenderer: Skia GL Pipeline
2020-11-23 00:22:20.244 24196-24196/com.example.weather W/example.weathe: Accessing hidden method Landroid/graphics/Insets;->of(IIII)Landroid/graphics/Insets; (light greylist, linking)
2020-11-23 00:22:20.257 24196-24276/com.example.weather D/HostConnection: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x729280ed9bc0, tid 24276
2020-11-23 00:22:20.381 24196-24276/com.example.weather D/HostConnection: HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v2 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v3 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v4 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_YUV420_888_to_NV21 ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_async_unmap_buffer GL_OES_EGL_image_external_essl3 GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_3_0 
2020-11-23 00:22:20.385 24196-24276/com.example.weather I/ConfigStore: android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasWideColorDisplay retrieved: 0
2020-11-23 00:22:20.385 24196-24276/com.example.weather I/ConfigStore: android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasHDRDisplay retrieved: 0
2020-11-23 00:22:20.385 24196-24276/com.example.weather I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
2020-11-23 00:22:20.385 24196-24276/com.example.weather D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
2020-11-23 00:22:20.385 24196-24276/com.example.weather W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
2020-11-23 00:22:20.385 24196-24276/com.example.weather D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 0
2020-11-23 00:22:20.389 24196-24276/com.example.weather D/eglCodecCommon: setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 0 0
2020-11-23 00:22:20.389 24196-24276/com.example.weather D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0x729280fe3b40: maj 3 min 0 rcv 3
2020-11-23 00:22:20.390 24196-24276/com.example.weather D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x729280fe3b40: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0x729280e59ca0)
2020-11-23 00:22:20.409 24196-24276/com.example.weather D/HostConnection: createUnique: call
2020-11-23 00:22:20.409 24196-24276/com.example.weather D/HostConnection: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x729280fe4040, tid 24276
2020-11-23 00:22:20.442 24196-24276/com.example.weather D/HostConnection: HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v2 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v3 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v4 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_YUV420_888_to_NV21 ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_async_unmap_buffer GL_OES_EGL_image_external_essl3 GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_3_0 
2020-11-23 00:22:20.442 24196-24276/com.example.weather E/eglCodecCommon: GoldfishAddressSpaceHostMemoryAllocator: ioctl_ping failed for device_type=5, ret=-1
2020-11-23 00:22:20.449 24196-24276/com.example.weather D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x729280fe3b40: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0x729280e59ca0)
2020-11-23 00:22:20.455 24196-24276/com.example.weather D/eglCodecCommon: setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 3 2
2020-11-23 00:22:25.904 24196-24196/com.example.weather W/ActivityThread: handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy@798fca3
2020-11-23 00:22:25.945 24196-24196/com.example.weather D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
2020-11-23 00:22:25.946 24196-24196/com.example.weather E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.weather, PID: 24196
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.weather/com.example.groupproject.weather}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2913)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.groupproject.weather.onCreate(weather.java:37)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2893)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858) 
2020-11-23 00:22:25.962 24196-24196/com.example.weather I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 24196 SIG: 9
```

main.java

```
package com.example.groupproject;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button btn;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btn = findViewById(R.id.button);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, weather.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }

}
```

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="150dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
        android:text="Weather"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

weather.java

```
package com.example.groupproject;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.example.groupproject.Retrofit.ApiInterface;
import com.example.groupproject.Retrofit.ApiClient;
import com.example.groupproject.Retrofit.Example;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;

public class weather extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageView search;
    TextView tempText, descText, humidityText;
    EditText textField;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        search = findViewById(R.id.search);
        tempText = findViewById(R.id.tempText);
        descText = findViewById(R.id.descText);
        humidityText = findViewById(R.id.humidityText);
        textField = findViewById(R.id.textField);


        search.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                //Here will call the API
                getWeatherData(textField.getText().toString().trim());
            }
        });
    }

    private void getWeatherData(String name) {

        ApiInterface apiInterface = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);

        Call<Example> call = apiInterface.getWeatherData(name);

        call.enqueue(new Callback<Example>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Example> call, Response<Example> response) {

                tempText.setText("Temp" + " " + response.body().getMain().getTemp() + "°C");
                descText.setText("Feel Like" + " " + response.body().getMain().getFeels_like() + "°C");
                humidityText.setText("Humidity" + " " + response.body().getMain().getHumidity() + "°C");
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Example> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });



    }

}
```

weather.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background = "@drawable/background">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:weightSum="3">


        <EditText
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2.5"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:background="#fff"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/textField"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:src="@drawable/search"
            android:id="@+id/search"/>


    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dp">



        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Text Temp"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="50dp"
            android:id="@+id/tempText"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Description"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            android:id="@+id/descText"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Humidity"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            android:id="@+id/humidityText"
            />


    </LinearLayout>









</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: can u share the logcat

Comment: I post it. thank you.

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 1):

In weather Activity you are setting content view of *activity_main.xml* instead of *weather.xml*

In weather Activity change this line

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

to

```
 setContentView(R.layout.weather);
```

Comment: thank you! It's work!
But the new error comes, when I click the button on my weather activity, come keeps stopping lol.

Comment: @Jen share the logcat